# How to join on an ID in JSONB

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Table `a` contains a list of apps (id, name). Table `b` contains a jsonb column with a user's sign in timestamps for apps (id, apps_last_accessed). I'm trying to get a list of apps ordered by the last accessed time for a specific user. The `apps_last_accessed` jsonb column contains an array of hashes with keys `local_id` which matches `a.id` and `published` which is a timestamp of the sign in time.

I have a query working where I select `FROM b` and the results are made into rows with `jsonb_array_elements`. These results are correct but don't mesh well with ActiveRecord's attempts to put the results into model objects, so I'm looking to do the same by selecting `FROM a`. Here is the working query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    j ->> 'published' as published
FROM
    b,
    jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed) as x(j)
JOIN a ON a.id = (j ->> 'local_id')::uuid
WHERE
    apps_last_accessed IS NOT NULL
    AND
    b.id = 'b9a528e2'
```

I basically need the inverse of this but I'm tripping up on how the join should be written. This is my attempt:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    j ->> 'published' as published
FROM
    a,
    b,
    jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed) as x(j)
JOIN b ON a.id = (j ->> 'local_id')::uuid
WHERE
    apps_last_accessed IS NOT NULL
    AND
    b.id = 'b9a528e2'
```

This is returning `ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "a"`.

Comment: what is the relation column  between a and be?

Comment: `a.id` matches `b.apps_last_accessed ->> 'local_id'`. Being jsonb, it's not a typical reference column.

Comment: There can be 0 to many `a`s referenced in one row of b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my approach would be making all cross joined tables to 1 in a sub query so that all columns from a and b and j are there to join.

```
CREATE tABLe a (id uuid, name text)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO a VALUES ('e764bf1d-e6d2-46d8-a206-b2db7cd797d3', 'A')
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM a
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| e764bf1d-e6d2-46d8-a206-b2db7cd797d3 | A |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
CREATE tABLe b (id varchar(8),apps_last_accessed jsonb)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
InSERt INTO b VALUES ('b9a528e2','[{"local_id":"e764bf1d-e6d2-46d8-a206-b2db7cd797d3", "published" : 1}]'::jsonB)
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.name,
    j ->> 'published' as published
FROM
    (SELECT a.id, b.id as id1,b.apps_last_accessed ,  a.name,j 
  FROM a,
    b,
    jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed) as x(j)) a
JOIN b ON a.id::uuid = (j ->> 'local_id')::uuid
WHERE
    a.apps_last_accessed IS NOT NULL
    AND
    a.id1 = 'b9a528e2'
```

| id | name | published |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e764bf1d-e6d2-46d8-a206-b2db7cd797d3 | A | 1 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rd2f4Xgm)

Comment: This works - thanks! I've noticed however that `LEFT JOIN` isn't working in the typical way in this scenario. Is there a way I can show `a` records for which there is no matching `local_id` in `b.apps_last_accessed`?

Comment: Make a dbfiddle with data and tell us in a new question what you are searching for, this approach isn't optimal, without a ncreze data we make a lot of assumptions

Comment: New Q with a fiddle is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583997/sort-by-item-in-jsonb-array-while-joining-on-the-same-array