# Sort by item in JSONB array, while joining on the same array

Tags: postgresql, join, jsonb

I'm aware at this point that a JSONB column was maybe not the best choice but I'm trying to avoid the creation of a new table just to make one column sortable.

I have a view in an app which displays the apps that a user has signed in to and I'd like to be able to sort it by login time. The login data is stored in a JSONB column. I'm using `jsonb_array_elements` to break out the array into rows. Initially I thought the results were duplicated from a JOIN but since the `published` time isn't the same for each app, I think the issue is getting the join to be limited to the correct JSONB array item.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/XaipOP1p

Schema/inserts:

```sql
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    id integer,
    name character varying,
    slug character varying
);
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, name, slug) VALUES (1, 'Okta', 'okta');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, name, slug) VALUES (2, 'Bitbucket', 'bitbucket');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, name, slug) VALUES (3, 'Salesforce', 'salesforce');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, name, slug) VALUES (4, 'Heroku', 'heroku');

CREATE TABLE supplier_sso_apps (
    id integer,
    supplier_id integer,
    target_supplier_id integer,
    sso_app_id character varying(512),
    sso_app_label character varying(512)
);
INSERT INTO supplier_sso_apps (id, supplier_id, sso_app_id, sso_app_label, target_supplier_id) VALUES (1, 1, '0oa2zi72tv1dhRGwt5d7', 'Bitbucket App', 2);
INSERT INTO supplier_sso_apps (id, supplier_id, sso_app_id, sso_app_label, target_supplier_id) VALUES (2, 1, '0oa6eb0tgusEP6WW45d7', 'Salesforce App', 3);
INSERT INTO supplier_sso_apps (id, supplier_id, sso_app_id, sso_app_label, target_supplier_id) VALUES (3, 1, '0oa2fabmgycm617Ug5d7', 'Heroku App 1', 4);
INSERT INTO supplier_sso_apps (id, supplier_id, sso_app_id, sso_app_label, target_supplier_id) VALUES (4, 1, '0oa2fagt7wngg7tNM5d7', 'Heroku App 2', 4);


CREATE TABLE sso_employees_apps (
    id integer,
    user_id integer,
    apps_last_accessed jsonb
);
INSERT INTO sso_employees_apps (id, user_id, apps_last_accessed) VALUES (1, 1, '[{"name": "Atlassian", "local_id": null, "published": "2023-06-06T00:20:16.217Z", "external_id": "0oa9gmxlpkjVzqmum5d7"}, {"name": "Bitbucket Yo", "local_id": "2", "published": "2023-06-06T00:19:58.236Z", "external_id": "0oa2zi72tv1dhRGwt5d7"}, {"name": "Salesforce App", "local_id": "3", "published": "2023-04-02T03:36:39.160Z", "external_id": "0oa6eb0tgusEP6WW45d7"}, {"name": "Heroku App 1", "local_id": "4", "published": "2023-06-14T17:23:22.982Z", "external_id": "0oa2fabmgycm617Ug5d7"}]');
INSERT INTO sso_employees_apps (id, user_id, apps_last_accessed) VALUES (2, 2, '[{"name": "Heroku App 1", "local_id": "4", "published": "2023-06-14T17:23:22.982Z", "external_id": "0oa2fabmgycm617Ug5d7"}, {"name": "Heroku App 2", "local_id": "4", "published": "2023-04-07T03:36:39.160Z", "external_id": "0oa2fagt7wngg7tNM5d7"}]');
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM suppliers;
SELECT * FROM supplier_sso_apps;
SELECT * FROM sso_employees_apps;

SELECT supplier_sso_apps.id, supplier_sso_apps.target_supplier_id, supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_id, supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_label, j ->> 'published' as published FROM
(
  SELECT supplier_sso_apps.id, supplier_sso_apps.target_supplier_id, supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_id, supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_label, j
  FROM supplier_sso_apps, sso_employees_apps, jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed) as x(j)
) supplier_sso_apps
JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id = supplier_sso_apps.target_supplier_id
LEFT JOIN sso_employees_apps ON supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_id = (j ->> 'external_id')
ORDER BY published ASC
```

I have `LEFT JOIN sso_employees_apps ON supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_id = (j ->> 'external_id')` but it seems this is joining a row where it's present, then duplicating for each item in `apps_last_accessed`. Any clues on how to restrict the join when it's happening with `jsonb_array_elements`?

Thank you in advance!

Update: The comments/answers are helpful but I need to provide more details on the goal. I'm iterating over `supplier_sso_apps` so I'd like `FROM supplier_sso_apps` to stay. The data where there's apps for which there's no matching supplier is intentional. I would like to only display rows where matches are present. I've altered the inserts and this results table is for user `1`. Here's the goal:

| Supplier Name | App Label | App ID | published |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Salesforce | Salesforce App | 0oa6eb0tgusEP6WW45d7 | 2023-04-02T03:36:39.160Z |
| Bitbucket | Bitbucket App | 0oa2zi72tv1dhRGwt5d7 | 2023-06-06T00:19:58.236Z |
| Heroku | Heroku App 1 | 0oa2fabmgycm617Ug5d7 | 2023-06-14T17:23:22.982Z |

Comment: Your fiddle does not look related to your question (the table has just a `text` column, and whose content does not look like json). Also, although providing a fiddle is clearly a bonus, it is good practice to put the data (or DDL) in the question directly (fiddle links eventually expire).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I brought the fiddle content into the question. The jsonb column is `sso_employees_apps.apps_last_accessed`. Is the array there not valid JSON? It seems to work with the `->>` selector regardless.

Comment: I don't know what is the purpose of cartesian join in your inner subquery, but I think you need [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/gxsQYvoR), or at least it will help. If not, please post desired result.

Answer (score 0):

With the constrict i choose you have access to all column without cross joining all columns, so to demonstrate it i added some columns to give you a better feeling, that you can access all data.

even if athe external link doesn't work, because the app doesn't exists, you still get a row that shows you and gives you the id to search for it

In general, you start with one table supplier_sso_apps  as we want the information from the json columns we cross join the data, so that we have access to all data, next we add table by table so that we can have all data we want the sort of JOIJ you need is deriveed from the data you want, so you alwas can start with an inner join and see if that is all the information that you want and so on, till you get all data in the select

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    id integer,
    name character varying,
    slug character varying
);
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, name, slug) VALUES (1, 'Okta', 'okta');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, name, slug) VALUES (2, 'Bitbucket', 'bitbucket');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, name, slug) VALUES (3, 'Salesforce', 'salesforce');
INSERT INTO suppliers (id, name, slug) VALUES (4, 'Heroku', 'heroku');

CREATE TABLE supplier_sso_apps (
    id integer,
    supplier_id integer,
    target_supplier_id integer,
    sso_app_id character varying(512),
    sso_app_label character varying(512)
);
INSERT INTO supplier_sso_apps (id, supplier_id, sso_app_id, sso_app_label, target_supplier_id) VALUES (1, 1, '0oa2zi72tv1dhRGwt5d7', 'Bitbucket App', 2);
INSERT INTO supplier_sso_apps (id, supplier_id, sso_app_id, sso_app_label, target_supplier_id) VALUES (2, 1, '0oa2fabmgycm617Ug5d7', 'Heroku App 1', 4);
INSERT INTO supplier_sso_apps (id, supplier_id, sso_app_id, sso_app_label, target_supplier_id) VALUES (3, 1, '0oa2fagt7wngg7tNM5d7', 'Heroku App 2', 4);

CREATE TABLE sso_employees_apps (
    id integer,
    user_id integer,
    apps_last_accessed jsonb
);
INSERT INTO sso_employees_apps (id, user_id, apps_last_accessed) VALUES (1, 1, '[{"name": "Atlassian", "local_id": null, "published": "2023-06-06T00:20:16.217Z", "external_id": "0oa9gmxlpkjVzqmum5d7"}, {"name": "Bitbucket Yo", "local_id": "2", "published": "2023-06-06T00:19:58.236Z", "external_id": "0oa2zi72tv1dhRGwt5d7"}]');
INSERT INTO sso_employees_apps (id, user_id, apps_last_accessed) VALUES (2, 2, '[{"name": "Heroku App 1", "local_id": "4", "published": "2023-06-14T17:23:22.982Z", "external_id": "0oa2fabmgycm617Ug5d7"}, {"name": "Heroku App 2", "local_id": "4", "published": "2023-04-07T03:36:39.160Z", "external_id": "0oa2fagt7wngg7tNM5d7"}]');
```

```
SELECT
(j ->> 'name') Apps_system ,supplier_sso_apps.id, supplier_sso_apps.target_supplier_id,suppliers.name,  (j ->> 'external_id') sso_app_id, supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_label, j ->> 'published' as published
  FROM
sso_employees_apps CROSS join jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed) as x(j) 
LEFT JOIN supplier_sso_apps ON supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_id = (j ->> 'external_id') 
LEFT   JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id = supplier_sso_apps.target_supplier_id
ORDER BY published ASC
```

| apps_system | id | target_supplier_id | name | sso_app_id | sso_app_label | published |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Heroku App 2 | 3 | 4 | Heroku | 0oa2fagt7wngg7tNM5d7 | Heroku App 2 | 2023-04-07T03:36:39.160Z |
| Bitbucket Yo | 1 | 2 | Bitbucket | 0oa2zi72tv1dhRGwt5d7 | Bitbucket App | 2023-06-06T00:19:58.236Z |
| Atlassian | *null* | *null* | *null* | 0oa9gmxlpkjVzqmum5d7 | *null* | 2023-06-06T00:20:16.217Z |
| Heroku App 1 | 2 | 4 | Heroku | 0oa2fabmgycm617Ug5d7 | Heroku App 1 | 2023-06-14T17:23:22.982Z |

```
SELECT
  suppliers.name,supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_label,(j ->> 'external_id') sso_app_id,j ->> 'published' as published

  FROM
sso_employees_apps CROSS join jsonb_array_elements(apps_last_accessed) as x(j) 
JOIN supplier_sso_apps ON supplier_sso_apps.sso_app_id = (j ->> 'external_id') 
JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.id = supplier_sso_apps.target_supplier_id
ORDER BY published ASC
```

| name | sso_app_label | sso_app_id | published |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Heroku | Heroku App 2 | 0oa2fagt7wngg7tNM5d7 | 2023-04-07T03:36:39.160Z |
| Bitbucket | Bitbucket App | 0oa2zi72tv1dhRGwt5d7 | 2023-06-06T00:19:58.236Z |
| Heroku | Heroku App 1 | 0oa2fabmgycm617Ug5d7 | 2023-06-14T17:23:22.982Z |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zAVxketH)

Comment: I've edited the question to have more information about the goal. Is it possible to use `cross join` from supplier_sso_apps?

Comment: like i said in the text you can select anything from the table that exists, the join give you the data you need the Select extracts the wanted information, you need to play around with the fiddle and add more queries to learn more about it. i have added anther query that gives you the result

Comment: The table of results isn't the end goal though. Rails' ActiveRecord has it's own expectations to be able to populate model objects. Is it not possible to iterate over `supplier_sso_apps` with `FROM supplier_sso_apps`? The challenge becomes the join on `sso_employees_apps` which was in the original question.

Comment: Also the data and results are different from the question and goal.

Comment: You have othr data than my in th sso_employees_apps  the first row has only 2 elements in the json yours has 4, so did you even try it out

Comment: Yes I tried it out and it wasn't the result I was looking for. Also if it isn't loading supplier_sso_apps then it can't be the answer I'm looking for due to ActiveRecord and other index conventions in this app.

Comment: With your data https://dbfiddle.uk/UqM1BZU8  you get 4 rows that fit the criteria, so which one should be eliminated to get 3 again

Comment: Like I've said, a query which uses `from sso_employees_apps` cannot be the answer I'm looking for. I need `from supplier_sso_apps`.

Comment: why , i don't understand joined tables can access all column from all tables, so why strt with supplier_sso_apps you got your data https://dbfiddle.uk/qxnARLAg independent of the staing point it is always the same result nothing changes

Comment: ActiveRecord populates objects based off the results. If  use sso_employees_apps, there's only one object. I'm not using the raw results.

Comment: the last lionk starts with supplier so.....

Comment: You mean in the `select`? ActiveRecord loads the model objects off of the `from`. If I feed that query into AR, it loads 4 instances of sso_employees_apps where none of the attributes are loaded. This is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: then ask a question about active records but i seems that joins are just fine, and not postgres, the query as it is works fine